# Android: CustomListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I have implemented a custom list view which looks like the twitter timeline.

```
adapter = new MyClickableListAdapter(this, R.layout.timeline, mObjectList);
       setListAdapter(adapter);
```

The constructor for MyClickableListAdapter is as follows

```
private class MyClickableListAdapter extends ClickableListAdapter{

  public MyClickableListAdapter(Context context, int viewId, List objects) {
   super(context, viewId, objects);
  }
```

ClickableListAdapter extends BaseAdapter and implements the necessary methods.

The xml code for the list view is as follows

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

This is what it [looks like](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?66c4ed3ea6.png).

I have 3 questions

**1)** I tried registering a context menu for the list view by adding the line after setting the list adapter

`registerforContextMenu(getListView())`;

But on long-click the menu doesnt get displayed. I cannot understand what I am doing wrong!

**2)** Is it possible to display a textview above the listview? I tried it by adding the code for textview above the listview. But then, only the textview gets displayed.

**3)** I have seen in many twitter clients that on clicking post in the options menu a window pops up from the top of the screen covering only as much its required and rest of the timeline is visible. How can this be done in Android? A window to enter the message and on pressing post the message is passed to the Activity that started it. The Window pops up from the top and takes only a quarter of the screen, rest of the screen displays the contents of the earlier activity.

Any help would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot understand what I am doing
>   wrong!

Did you implement onCreateContextMenu()?

> Is it possible to display a textview
>   above the listview?

Yes.

> I tried it by adding the code for
>   textview above the listview. But then,
>   only the textview gets displayed.

See [this sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Selection/List/) from one of my books for a `TextView` above a `ListView`.

How can this be done possibly without starting a new activity?

It is a little difficult to answer that given your description. My guess is that it is via an animation. See [this sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/27-Animation/) from another one of my books for a Twitter client where the field and button for a status update can be hidden and shown via an option menu choice and an animation.

Comment: Yes, I implemented onCreateContextMenu(). Is there some-other way to show a menu for items in the list?

I've edited the 3rd question to be more clear..

Comment: "Is there some-other way to show a menu for items in the list?" -- no your approach is correct. See here for a sample project implementing a context menu on a ListView: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Database/Constants/  With respect to your question #3, that might be a `PopupWindow`.

Comment: How do I implement a PopupWindow? Is it possible to get input in a PopupWindow?